# Push jenkins build to git repo

Tags: git, maven, heroku, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repo where I do all my work. It has a master and development branch. When I merge the development branch to master I trigger a jenkins maven build that assembles my project into a output (target) folder in the workspace. How would I go about pushing the contents of that output folder to another remote git repo (heroku)? I figure the git publisher post-action would help me with this, but if I understand correctly it will just push the branch directly to heroku, not the actual output of the maven build.

Comment: It's not a good practice to store build artifacts in a git repository, consider using a build artifact repository manager.

Comment: The thing is that the heroku git repo is deployed. Not everything in my bitbucket working repo is suppose to be deployed. So I want the jenkins build to produce what is to be deployed and then push only that to heroku.